# PHP - create and call SOAP web service - error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Every time i try to make a call to my webservice, through the wsdl, i get the error message shown here.  I think its probably an issue within the the WSDL defintion, because I am not really sure what i am doing within the WSDL definition to begin with:

```
 [22-Sep-2011 18:54:46] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception:
 [HTTP] Not Found in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/csc/request.php:4
 Stack trace:
 #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...',
 'http://192.168....', 'http://www.exam...', 1, 0)
 #1 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('EchoText', Array)
 #2 /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/csc/request.php(4):
 SoapClient->EchoText('test')
 #3 {main}   thrown in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/csc/request.php on
 line 4
```

---

I have a very simple web service, located at:
http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/csc.php

```
<?php

function EchoText($text){
    return "ECHO: ".$text;
}

$server = new SoapServer(null,
                         array('uri' => "http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/csc.php"));
$server->addFunction('EchoText');
$server->handle();

?>
```

---

I have an interfacing page, which is what i access and then get the error shown above, located at:
http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/request.php

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile.wsdl");

$result = $client->EchoText("test");
echo $result;
>?
```

---

I have my WSDL, located at:
http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile.wsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="NewWSDLFile" targetNamespace="http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile.wsdl">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile.wsdl">
      <xsd:element name="EchoText">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="EchoTextResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="EchoTextRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:EchoText" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="EchoTextResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:EchoText" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="NewWSDLFile">
    <wsdl:operation name="EchoText">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:EchoTextRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:EchoTextResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="NewWSDLFileSOAP" type="tns:NewWSDLFile">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="EchoText">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/NewWSDLFile/EchoText"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="NewWSDLFile">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:NewWSDLFileSOAP" name="NewWSDLFileSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/csc.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

---

UPDATE..

I was able to get more detailed information on the error message by doing a try catch and print_r($e);... here is the detailed error message:

```
SoapFault Object (
  [message:protected] => Not Found
  [string:private] =>
  [code:protected] => 0
  [file:protected] => /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/csc/request.php
  [line:protected] => 7
  [trace:private] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
      [function] => __doRequest
      [class] => SoapClient
      [type] => ->
      [args] => Array (
         [0] =>
         [1] => http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/csc.wsdl
         [2] => http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/EchoText
         [3] => 1
         [4] => 0
      )
    )
   [1] => Array (
      [function] => __call
      [class] => SoapClient
      [type] => ->
      [args] => Array (
         [0] => EchoText
         [1] => Array (
             [0] => test
         )
      )
    )
   [2] => Array (
      [file] => /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/csc/request.php
      [line] => 7
      [function] => EchoText
      [class] => SoapClient
      [type] => ->
      [args] => Array ( 
         [0] => test
      )
    )
  )
  [faultstring] => Not Found
  [faultcode] => HTTP
)
```

Comment: [0] => Array (
      [function] => __doRequest
      [class] => SoapClient
      [type] => ->
      [args] => Array (
         [0] =>
         [1] => **http://192.168.1.2:10088/csc/csc.wsdl**
 It seems, your WSDL file is misinterpretted. this is just a doubt, which might help you

Answer (score 1):

SoapFault => Not Found is that the SoapClient can't reach the server.

192.168.1.2 is a local IP-address, is the web server also on the local network? Otherwise that is the reason why your client isn't working.

Comment: everything used and referenced in this project is on our local network. aside from the "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" portion of the wsdl.  I did find one interesting thing,  in the detailed error message at the bottom of my post you will see " http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/EchoText", but this is not in any of my files! i have also cleared my cache to make sure its current... i have no idea how this is getting in there.

Comment: What language are you writing the web services in?

Comment: PHP, 5.2.13     using apache server.

Comment: i am continuing this post in a different question.  as the error message and issue has changed... although the URL's used are still the same.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561604/object-hasnt-in-property-php-soap-wsdl